# Make only particular features on layer selectable

Tags: openlayers

I'm using a select interaction. I can filter the layers which are selectable using a filter function as the `layers` option key. I want to also filter which features are selectable.

The [documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html?unstable=true) says "Which features are selected is determined by the `condition` option". I am therefore trying to write a function for the `condition` option which can filter out particular features. But I'm not sure it's possible. I think the quoted documentation may be misleading.

The `condition` function takes an event argument. I first filter out any events which aren't of the `click` type, but then I want to filter on features. The event has a `target` property, but it's not clear to me what this is pointing to. It doesn't appear to be a layer or a feature.

I do have the pixel coordinates and the map coordinates at the clicked point. I could use either of these to loop over features at that point in the layer and, if I deem one of them selectable, return true. But what if there are two overlapping features, one of which I want to be selectable and one not?

I'm guessing this `condition` option is not what I'm looking for, since it is run once per event, not once per possible feature. Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The feature made it into Openlayers 3 master branch recently from https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3402 -- it'll be in 3.5.0. The following is working for me:

```
var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
    layers: function(layer) {
        return /* some logic on layer to decide if its features should be considered; return true if yes */;
    },
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return /* some logic on a feature and layer to decide if it should be selectable; return true if yes */;
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a lot of discussion regarding this here: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3257

Comment: Thanks for that. From https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3277 (linked from the above) it seems that the feature should be available as a `filter` option to the select interaction with release 3.4.0.